# How to set parameters inside header in PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to make SOAP petitions where there must be an Addressing parameter declared inside the Header.

Here's my code in PHP:

```
    $params = array(); 
    $params['xmlns:tem'] = "http://tempuri.org/";
    $params['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;
    $params['trace'] = 1;

    $client = new SoapClient("myurl",$params);
    $header = array();
    $header[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', "Action", "myurlAction");
    $header[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', "To", "myurlTo");
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $result = $client->myCall()
```

To get the results, I have to declare the wsa inside the header like this (notice the ns2 parameter declared in Header):

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <env:Header xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  .... 
</env:Header>
```

The avobe XML returns the data, so it's what I want the php to generate.

But with my PHP code I get this result (the parameter ns2 is declared in the Envelope instead):

```
<env:Envelope
xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header> ... </env:Header>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you...

Comment: Element's XML namespace could be defined on any parent of this element, up the hierarchy. So the location of `xmlns:ns2` in those two examples are equivalent, that is the receiving side should understand both of these SOAP requests the same way, as long as it doesn't try to interpret the XML request literally as string.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to force the namespace to be declared in the header? I don't have control over the SOAP server, so I assume they interpret the XML literally as a string, because I ran tests in SoapUI and it only works if the namespace are declared in the header